# Optimum solution for 1-D linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model

Consider linear regression in 1 dimension. Total loss is expressed thusly:

$$L(w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(wx_i-y_i)^2$$

I need to show 3 things. First, I need to compute the optimal solution $w^*$ for a batch of examples $(x_i,y_i), 1 \leq i \leq n$, by minimizing total loss.

Second, I need to assume labels are expensive and that I am only given one label $y_i$, then compute the optimal solution $w_i^*$ based on a single example $(x_i,y_i)$.

Third, I need to show that if $i$ is chosen wrt the distribution $\frac{x_i^2}{\sum_{j}x_j^2}$, the expected loss of $w_i^*$ on all examples is twice the optimum:

$$\mathbb{E}[L(w_i^*)]=2L(w^*)$$

I know that the optimal solution equation for the batch should be:

$$w^*=argmin_w \sum_{i}(x_iw-y_i)^2$$

However, I am not sure how to approach it.

The only hint for the 3rd part I have is to try to show:

$$\mathbb{E}[L(w_i^*)]=2y^2-\frac{2}{x^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}y_iy_jx_ix_j=2L(w^*)$$

Where $x$ is the vector of points and $y$ is the vector of labels.

Any help, hints, or links to resources would be appreciated.

Comment: hint: differentiate the objective function respect to $w$